# sorting database data by author in alphabetical order

Tags: java, mysql, swing

Hello everyone I have SQL database with 3 tables ( type,author,warehouse) and they are connected with IDs , I want a sort by Author in alphabetical order my tables .I have somthing written ,but not worked

```
public List<String> authorAlphabeticReference() {
Warehouse w1 = new Warehouse();
Collections.sort(warehouses,new TypeComparator());
List<String> w2 = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i <warehouses.size(); i++) {
    w1 =  warehouses.get(i);
    if(w1.getAuthor().equals(w2))
        w2.add(w1);
}
Collections.sort(w2);
return w2;
```

Comment: If your data is in an SQL database, you should run a _query_ to obtain the rows in the order you require – you need not "sort them" yourself.